# form.submit method is not work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

## Form

```
 <form method="POST" name="form" id="form">
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="ans1" value="A"> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ans2" value="B"> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ans3" value="C"> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ans4" value="D"> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="send">  
        </p>
     </form>
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if(endTime <= time )
    {
        //alert('123'); //when fire condition then alert is working ;
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

## Problem

When i click on send button then form submit by php 
 but if form does not submit i want to submit form automatic by jQuery , **but form.submit is not working**

**When jQuery 'if condition' fire then page reload and hang page but form did not submit**

Comment: Where you have defined `endTime` and `time` and How are they populated?

Comment: i have defined in jQuery endTime and time

Comment: @ErSahajArora  form may be submitted but because at the time of form submit no radion button is checked so you are getting nothing in $_POST.so may be it seems to you that form is not submitting

Comment: `'if condition' fire then page reload` Which means the form is submited then see Anant's comment above

Comment: @ErSahajArora  what you actually want to achieve

Comment: i want when condition fire then form should submit , it's does not submitted

Comment: Because your condition isn't resolving to true. Please post all of your cost and explain clearly what it is that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you call $( "#form" ).submit(); it triggers the external submit handler which prevents the default action, instead use

```
$( "#form" )[0].submit();
```

or

```
$form.submit();//declare `$form as a local variable by using var $form = this;
```

> When you call the dom element's submit method programatically, it
>   won't trigger the submit handlers attached to the element

Comment: `it triggers the external submit handler which prevents the default action` Nothing in opening question suggests it

Answer (score 1):

Try submitting the form using javascript if it works :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if(endTime <= time )
    {
        //alert('123'); //when fire condition then alert is working ;
        document.getElementById("form").submit()
    }
});
```

And secondly, it's not a good practice to name a form *form*

Comment: i already try this but form didn't submit , alert is working means condition fire